# Compiling c++ using llvm & visual studio 2013 with BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, llvm

I am trying to compile with llvm in MS Visual Studio 2013 but the minute I use BOOST I get errors which I can't solve.
Here is the simple code I use:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void doAbsolutelyNothingForever()
{
    while (true);
}

int main()
{
    //boost::thread t(doAbsolutelyNothingForever);
    //t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

To which I get many errors. So my next guess was to build boost and compile it with clang. After doing so, I still get the same errors.
And here are the errors:

> 1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(27,9):
>   error : unknown type name '_Atomic'   1>  typedef _Atomic(
>   boost::int_least32_t ) atomic_int_least32_t;  1>          ^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(27,25):
>   error : cannot define or redeclare 'int_least32_t' here because
>   namespace 'detail' does not enclose namespace 'boost'     1>  typedef
>   _Atomic( boost::int_least32_t ) atomic_int_least32_t;     1>                   ~~~~~~~^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(27,25):
>   error : typedef declarator cannot be qualified    1>  typedef _Atomic(
>   boost::int_least32_t ) atomic_int_least32_t;  1>
>   ~~~~~~~^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(27,40):
>   error : expected ';' after top level declarator   1>  typedef _Atomic(
>   boost::int_least32_t ) atomic_int_least32_t;  1>
>   ^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(29,31):
>   error : unknown type name 'atomic_int_least32_t'  1>  inline void
>   atomic_increment( atomic_int_least32_t * pw )     1>
>   ^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(34,47):
>   error : unknown type name 'atomic_int_least32_t'  1>  inline
>   boost::int_least32_t atomic_decrement( atomic_int_least32_t * pw )    1>
>   ^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(39,59):
>   error : unknown type name 'atomic_int_least32_t'  1>  inline
>   boost::int_least32_t atomic_conditional_increment(
>   atomic_int_least32_t * pw )   1>
>   ^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(68,5):
>   error : unknown type name 'atomic_int_least32_t'  1>
>   atomic_int_least32_t use_count_;    // #shared    1>      ^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(69,5):
>   error : unknown type name 'atomic_int_least32_t'  1>
>   atomic_int_least32_t weak_count_;   // #weak + (#shared != 0)     1>
>   ^
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp(132,47):
>   error : unknown type name 'atomic_int_least32_t'  1>          return
>   __c11_atomic_load( const_cast< atomic_int_least32_t* >( &use_count_ ), __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE );    1>                                                ^     1>  In file included from Source.cpp:1:     1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\thread.hpp:13:    1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:     1>  In file
>   included from d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15:
>     1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:11:
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp(183,54):
>   error : redeclaration of 'Sleep' cannot add 'dllimport' attribute     1> 
>   __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall Sleep(unsigned long);    1>                                                       ^  1>  d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/yield_k.hpp(63,29)
>   :  note: previous declaration is here     1>    extern "C" void __stdcall
>   Sleep( unsigned long ms );    1>                              ^   1>  In
>   file included from Source.cpp:1:  1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\thread.hpp:13:    1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:     1>  In file
>   included from d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15:
>     1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:11:
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp(418,21):
>   error : no member named 'Sleep' in namespace 'boost::detail::win32';
>   did you mean simply 'Sleep'?  1>
>   ::boost::detail::win32::Sleep(0);     1>
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  1> 
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/smart_ptr/detail/yield_k.hpp(63,29) : 
>   note: 'Sleep' declared here   1>    extern "C" void __stdcall Sleep(
>   unsigned long ms );   1>                              ^   1>  In file
>   included from Source.cpp:1:   1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\thread.hpp:13:    1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:     1>  In file
>   included from d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15:
>     1>  In file included from
>   d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:11:
>     1>d:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp(426,45):
>   error : no type named 'Sleep' in namespace 'boost::detail::win32'     1> 
>   ::boost::detail::win32::Sleep(milliseconds);  1>
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^     1>  13 errors generated.    ========== Build:
>   0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: LLVM-VS isn't even remotely ready for prime time so I don't know what this question is about.